# How to save Powershell's output to file when I create synthetic voice audio with Text-to-Speech using the command line

Tags: powershell, ssml, gtts

please teach me how to make Powershell automatically save its tts output to TEXT file, as I'm getting just a long string like this:

{
  "audioContent": "//NExAAQ4oIMABhEuDRESizqE7uehfMY8A...........

I have to process more than 1400 files :( what to do? 
Also is there a way to upload text more than 5000 symbols long? 
Also is it possible to automatically create SSML from HTML?

I've made everything as described in this [Document](http://ggoogle.top/g0/index.php?q=oKipp7eAc2SUrbLkr5fX36bMrchgtt7ie-TL5sB84OBktsi_m8zTnqu2qeBlo6rZrtDW18Lb5aCxu7zjkJjUpA)

Comment: As the document you refer to says [here](http://ggoogle.top/g0/index.php?q=oKipp7eAc2SUrbLkr5fX36bMrchgtt7ie-TL5sB84OBktsi_m8zTnqu2qeBlo6rZrtDW18Lb5aCxu7zjkJjUpA#powershell-windows), convert the json and save the `.audioContent` to text file.

Comment: Do You propose to make it manualy 1400 times?

Comment: Show your code so far pls.

Comment: For details please follow the link "Document" in my first message. It is the same and formatted well there.

last step (PowerShell request) is


$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }

Invoke-WebRequest `
  -Method POST `
  -Headers $headers `
  -ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
  -InFile request.json `
  -Uri "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" | Select-Object -Expand Content

Comment: And so, the object you get has a property called `audioContent` that holds the base64 you need to save to text file. What is the problem here?

Comment: as i have 1400+ text files to convert, i'd like to write a script for powershell with already embedded 1400+ texts to convert.  the output, audioContent must be automatically saved in text file. NOT MANUALY. The problem, Theo, is that i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not quite sure what you mean here.. Are you saying that you have a lot of text files that now have content `{ "audioContent": "//NExAAQ4oIMABhEuDRESizqE7uehfMY8A...........` and you need to replace that content with just the part between the curly brackets?

If that is the case, you can do

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'ThePathToLookForTheFiles' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Set-Content -Value (($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace '^\{\s*"audioContent":\s*"([^}]+)\}', '$1')
}
```

For any new textfile, change the code from [here](http://ggoogle.top/g0/index.php?q=oKipp7eAc2SUrbLkr5fX36bMrchgtt7ie-TL5sB84OBktsi_m8zTnqu2qeBlo6rZrtDW18Lb5aCxu7zjkJjUpA#synthesize_audio_from_text) a bit by capturing the result from the `Invoke-WebRequest` and saving the `audioContent` property to text file:

```
$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }

$params = @{
    Method      = 'POST'
    Headers     = $headers
    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    InFile      = 'request.json'
    Uri         = "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize"
}

$content = Invoke-WebRequest @params | Select-Object -Expand Content
# save the textfile with just the base64 string:
Set-Content -Path 'TheFullPathAndFileName' -Value $content.audioContent
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for help! Unfortunately I've got an error

Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
line: 1 character: 12
+ $content = Invoke-WebRequest @params | Select-Object -Expand Content
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: @ДмитрийЧалый then there is something wrong with your credentials I'm afraid..